# Can't deploy next.js app with aws amplify on netlify or vercel

Tags: next.js, vercel, netlify

Can't run next.js app on netlfiy or vercel. Everything is working fine locally. Getting the same error on both netlify and vercel when I visit one of my pages. Every page has **getServerSideProps** so it is run as a serverless function (e.g: /login) but when I run it I get the errors in the images attached below.

Not sure why, but I have tried adding env variables of aws to netlify and vercel as well but no luck. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Serverless Logs for netlify and vercel: https://imgur.com/a/qtYMPZj

my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@aws-amplify/ui-react": "^4.3.6",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.11.0",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.11.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^6.2.1",
    "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "^6.2.1",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.2.0",
    "@headlessui/react": "^1.7.13",
    "@material-tailwind/react": "^1.2.5",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.9.3",
    "@szhsin/react-menu": "^3.4.1",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "@types/googlemaps": "^3.43.3",
    "@types/jest": "^27.5.2",
    "@types/node": "^16.18.11",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.27",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.10",
    "@types/react-fontawesome": "^1.6.5",
    "antd": "^5.5.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.13",
    "aws-amplify": "^5.1.1",
    "aws-appsync-codegen": "^0.17.5",
    "cookies-next": "^2.1.1",
    "graphql-tag": "^2.12.6",
    "jose": "^4.13.1",
    "next": "^13.1.6",
    "next-redux-cookie-wrapper": "^2.2.1",
    "next-redux-wrapper": "^8.1.0",
    "next-seo": "^5.15.0",
    "rc-collapse": "^3.5.2",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.43.9",
    "react-icons": "^4.7.1",
    "react-lazy-load-image-component": "^1.5.6",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.5",
    "react-slick": "^0.29.0",
    "react-use-websocket": "^4.3.1",
    "slick-carousel": "^1.8.1",
    "tw-elements": "^1.0.0-alpha13",
    "tw-to-css": "^0.0.11",
    "typescript": "^4.9.4",
    "uuid": "^9.0.0",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "start": "next start",
    "build": "next build",
    "lint": "eslint --fix \"**/*.{ts,tsx}\"",
    "codegen": "aws-appsync-codegen generate src/graphql/operations/*.ts --schema backend/lib/appsync/build/schema.json --target typescript --output src/graphql/types/types.ts"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react-lazy-load-image-component": "^1.5.2",
    "@types/react-slick": "^0.23.10",
    "@types/uuid": "^9.0.1",
    "eslint": "^8.33.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "13.0.4",
    "sass": "^1.62.1",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.2.4"
  }
}
```

Using

```
Amplify.configure({ amplifyConfig, ssr: true });
```

`amplifyConfig` will have sth like (has more attributes than this):

```
{
 aws_project_region: '***********************',
 aws_cognito_identity_pool_id: '***********************',
 aws_cognito_region: '***********************',
 aws_user_pools_id: '***********************',
 aws_user_pools_web_client_id: '***********************',
}
```

Comment: Are you using environment variables locally but forgetting to input them in the project's settings? Your amplifyConfig seems not using process.env.XXX to read the .env

Comment: @TomFan firstly, thank you for trying to help. Also I'm simply using an object instead of env to fill in those aws values for our project. So they should just be included without any issue.